# Installing Windows 10 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10

About a month ago, my Windows crashed (I was dual booting), giving me the BSoD. I couldn't find any other solution, so I formatted my drive and installed only Ubuntu. Now, however, I require Windows for some urgent work, but I do not want to lose my Ubuntu files. How do I install Windows alongside Ubuntu 18.04? I have an HP Pavilion 15 laptop. I tried contacting HP but they were of no help with Ubuntu.

UPDATE: I am trying to create a partition for Windows using GParted but I'm not being able to. [Whenever I try to change partition size, it reverts back to the original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R4vz.png)

Comment: A quick and no-risk solution would be installing Windows in a virtual machine, e.g. using Virtualbox. If that is a viable solution depends on your hardware and what you want to do in Windows. I'd just try it, it's the quickest and most hassle-free solution.

Comment: @danzel I have considered using a VM only for the work, but I'd also like to install games on my laptop. Installing Windows would be a preferable solution.

Comment: Open [GParted](https://linuxhint.com/gparted_ubuntu/) and create an empty partition for your windows . Then follow the installation procedure of windows. I've personally never installed windows after ubuntu , so your grub menu might fail to appear and instead your windows boots up directly. I don't know . But if that happened , you can boot a live linux ISO and then run "update-grub" to make grub2 the default bootloader for your system.

Comment: If you cannot shrink the partition you're currently on , consider booting a live ISO and shrink your ext4 partition from there.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi as you can see from the screenshot I have attached, I am not being able to resize dev/sda2 to make room for a Windows partition. I will try the rest as and when I am able to solve this.

Comment: @aayush-a Have you tried it with a live ISO ?

Comment: @aayush-a In order to resize a partition you have to first unmount it , and you cannot unmount a partition that you're currently using . So please try it a live ISO.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi okay, makes sense. Will try it out.